# Hi everyone, DAY time long exposure

Tags: long-exposure, manual-mode, bulb-mode, canon-70d

I have a question regarding Day time long exposure:
I have a canon 70d 50mm 1.8 lens and 18-135mm; when I try to shoot a long exposure during the day iso 100, f16 mode BULB.......the picture is white all the time, I do not know what i am doing wrong.....

thanks all for your advises in advance

Comment: The question linked above isn't exactly the same, however the answers still answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

There is simply too mich light.

You can use ND filters to reduce the amount of light that reaches the sensor.